# Oracle row_number/rank with specific logic

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ranking, row-number

I need to choose some mechanism for ranking rows with row_number or rank. I am tried to use both cases RNK1, RNK2 columns, but I am not sure if it is possible at all. Please see the actual and expected result.

```
with tmp as (
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual
) 
select 
    tmp.*,
    case when flag = 1 then row_number() over(partition by flag order by flag) else null end as rnk1,
    case when flag = 1 then rank() over(partition by flag order by flag) else null end as rnk2
from tmp
order by startdate, username
```

Actual:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| "USERNAME"  | "STARTDATE"        | "FLAG" | "RNK1" | "RNK2" |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 00:00:00 | 1      | 6      | 1      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 01:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 4      | 1      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 3      | 1      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 01:00:00 | 1      | 5      | 1      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 1      | 1      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 2      | 1      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Expected:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| "USERNAME"  | "STARTDATE"        | "FLAG" | "RNK1" | "RNK2" |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 00:00:00 | 1      | 1      | 1      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 01:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 2      | 2      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 2      | 2      |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 01:00:00 | 1      | 3      | 3      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 3      | 3      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 3      | 3      |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |        |        |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

Thanks all for a quick response. I started to play with your proposals and stuck again

```
with tmp as (
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual
) 
select 
    tmp.*,
    dense_rank() over( order by startdate, username, threshold)-
     (case when flag=1 then
     row_number()over(partition by flag, username order by startdate, username) - flag
      else null end) as grp
from tmp
order by 
startdate, username
```

Actual:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| "USERNAME"  | "STARTDATE"        | "FLAG" | "THRESHOLD" | "GRP" |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 00:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 1     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 01:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 2     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      |             | 2     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 01:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      |             | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 04:00:00 | 1      |             | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

Expected:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| "USERNAME"  | "STARTDATE"        | "FLAG" | "THRESHOLD" | "GRP" |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 00:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 1     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 01:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 2     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      |             | 2     |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 04:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 01-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 01:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 02:00:00 | 1      |             | 4     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 03:00:00 | 1      | 1           | 5     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 04:00:00 | 1      |             | 5     |
| "username1" | 02-APR-19 05:00:00 | 0      |             |       |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to *explain* your expected results - you haven't said what your logic is.

Comment: kovitals, why grp = 3 is not present in expeted result?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're grouping consecutive flag = 1 rows, you can do this using a combination of the [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) technique and a dense_rank, like so:

```
WITH      tmp AS (select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual),
  tabibitosan AS (SELECT tmp.*,
                         CASE
                           WHEN flag = 1 THEN
                            row_number() over(ORDER BY startdate) - row_number() over(PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY startdate)
                         END grp
                  FROM   tmp)
SELECT username,
       startdate,
       flag,
       CASE
         WHEN flag = 1 THEN
          dense_rank() over(PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY grp)
       END rnk
FROM   tabibitosan
ORDER  BY startdate,
          username;

USERNAME  STARTDATE                 FLAG        RNK
--------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
username1 01/04/2019 00:00:00          1          1
username1 01/04/2019 01:00:00          0 
username1 01/04/2019 02:00:00          1          2
username1 01/04/2019 03:00:00          1          2
username1 01/04/2019 04:00:00          0 
username1 02/04/2019 01:00:00          1          3
username1 02/04/2019 02:00:00          1          3
username1 02/04/2019 03:00:00          1          3
username1 02/04/2019 04:00:00          0 
username1 02/04/2019 05:00:00          0
```

---

I've updated the query to take account of the extra threshold column:

```
WITH      tmp AS (select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
                  select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual),
  tabibitosan AS (SELECT tmp.*,
                         CASE
                           WHEN flag = 1 THEN
                            row_number() over(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY startdate) - row_number() over(PARTITION BY username, flag ORDER BY startdate)
                         END grp,
                         SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN threshold END) OVER (PARTITION BY username, flag ORDER BY startdate) threshold_sum -- assumes threshold is 1 or null; change the case statement inside the sum if this isn't the case
                  FROM   tmp)
SELECT username,
       startdate,
       flag,
       threshold,
       CASE
         WHEN flag = 1 THEN
          dense_rank() over(PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY grp, threshold_sum)
       END rnk
FROM   tabibitosan
ORDER  BY startdate,
          username;

USERNAME  STARTDATE         FLAG  THRESHOLD        RNK
--------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
username1 01/04/2019           1          1          1
username1 01/04/2019           0            
username1 01/04/2019           1          1          2
username1 01/04/2019           1                     2
username1 01/04/2019           0            
username1 01/04/2019           0            
username1 02/04/2019           1                     3
username1 02/04/2019           1          1          4
username1 02/04/2019           1          1          5
username1 02/04/2019           1                     5
username1 02/04/2019           0
```

N.B. I've assumed the threshold column can only be 1 or null; if that's not the case, you will have to update the conditional sum according to your data.

I've also updated the partitioning of the analytic functions to include the username column, since I'm assuming this is the primary key for the data.

Finally, note that I have changed your sample data slightly, to show that if the threshold is null for the first row in the group with flag = 1, it will be in its own group, if the next row has the threshold set. If that's not the behaviour you desire, you need to update your question with the logic you desire.

Comment: What if first flag = 0?

Comment: If the first row has flag != 1, it'll work exactly the same. I wonder why you think it would work any differently?

Comment: please check my last post in topic

Comment: @kovitals I've updated my answer to include a query for the additional threshold column. When you ask a question in the future, please make sure you include the case that you're really after, and please remember to include the logic behind whatever the desired results are. Thank you for the way you included your sample data; it made it very easy to help.

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
with tmp as (
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
    select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual
) 
select 
    tmp.*,
    dense_rank() over( order by startdate, username)-
     (case when flag=1 then
     row_number()over(partition by flag, username order by startdate, username) - flag
      else null end) as grp


from tmp
order by 
startdate, username


USERNAME    STARTDATE   FLAG    GRP
username1   01-APR-19   1       1
username1   01-APR-19   0   
username1   01-APR-19   1       2
username1   01-APR-19   1       2
username1   01-APR-19   0   
username1   02-APR-19   1       3
username1   02-APR-19   1       3
username1   02-APR-19   1       3
username1   02-APR-19   0   
username1   02-APR-19   0
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2b790279ea49151900243c395d8bd4a)

Comment: What if first flag = 0?

Comment: @akk0rd87 do you have same problem?

Comment: If first flag = 0 your grp will be start from 3.

Comment: please check my last post in topic

Answer (score 1):

```
with tmp as (
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, 1 as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag, null as threshold from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag, null as threshold from dual
) 
select tmp.*, decode(flag, 1, count(threshold) over (partition by username order by startdate)) rn
from tmp;

USERNAME  STARTDATE                 FLAG  THRESHOLD         RN
--------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
username1 2019-04-01 00:00:00          1          1          1
username1 2019-04-01 01:00:00          0                      
username1 2019-04-01 02:00:00          1          1          2
username1 2019-04-01 03:00:00          1                     2
username1 2019-04-01 04:00:00          0                      
username1 2019-04-01 05:00:00          0                      
username1 2019-04-02 01:00:00          1          1          3
username1 2019-04-02 02:00:00          1                     3
username1 2019-04-02 03:00:00          1          1          4
username1 2019-04-02 04:00:00          1                     4
username1 2019-04-02 05:00:00          0                      

11 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with tmp as (
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-01 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 1 as flag  from dual union all
select 'username1' as username, to_date('2019-04-02 04:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as startdate, 0 as flag  from dual
) 
select username, startdate, flag, decode(flag, 1, match_num) as rn
from tmp
match_recognize(
partition by username
order by startdate
measures match_number() AS match_num
all rows per match
pattern (s* f*)
define f as f.flag = 1, s as s.flag = 0
);

USERNAME  STARTDATE                 FLAG         RN
--------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
username1 2019-04-01 00:00:00          1          1
username1 2019-04-01 01:00:00          0           
username1 2019-04-01 02:00:00          1          2
username1 2019-04-01 03:00:00          1          2
username1 2019-04-01 04:00:00          0           
username1 2019-04-02 01:00:00          1          3
username1 2019-04-02 02:00:00          1          3
username1 2019-04-02 03:00:00          1          3
username1 2019-04-02 04:00:00          0           
username1 2019-04-02 05:00:00          0           

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: This will only work if there are only two flag values (which may, of course, be what the OP has), but it won't work if the flag value could be null (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2fb05f5697e2c6e38cd0357e3025a95); the pattern definition for `s` would need to be updated to make it work for all cases. Also, it won't work in 11g, which is what the OP has tagged.

Comment: If flag could be null just use nvl(s.flag, 0) = 0. Yes, pattern matching does not useful for Oracle 11g. Only 12+.